# (*var)[n] what does it mean in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

What does (*var)[n] mean in C++? In this code I know that it refers to getting the captured string from regex matches of group n, but I don't understand why this doesn't work:

```
*var[n] //edit: oh duh, that would be a multiplication
```

what's up with the parenthesis? reminds me of casting, all 3 gives the same results:

```
(char*)filename[0]
const_cast<char*>(filename.c_str())
&filename[0]
```

but (char*) and (*it) have the asterisk in different places.

```
    regex expr("[_-]?([a-gA-G]#?(?:-2|-1|[0-8]))");
    int found = 0;
    for (sregex_iterator it(tagstruct.name.begin(), tagstruct.name.end(), expr), itEnd; it != itEnd; ++it) {
        if ((*it)[1] != "") {
            notename = (*it)[1];
            if (++found >= search_count) {
                f = NoteNameToFreq(notename);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `*` is for indirecting through a pointer variable.

Comment: `*var[n]` is not the same as `(*var)[n]`. Subscripting has higher precedence, so it's equivalent to `*(var[n])`.

Comment: `(char*)` is type casting.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's non-constructive!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(*var)` means that `var` is a pointer variable, and it will indirect through the pointer to access the object it points to. Adding `[n]` means that it points to an array, and this will then access the `n`th element of the array.

Don't confuse `(*var)[n]` with `*var[n]`. The latter is equivalent to `*(var[n])`. This means that `var` is an array of pointers. It gets the `n`th element of the array, and then accesses the object it points to.

`(type*)` is C-style type casting, it converts the value after this to the specified pointer type.